# My laptop battery "Is not charging" after recent update of Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, thinkpad

About two weeks ago after some system update of Ubuntu 21.10 my battery stopped charging when the power cord is plugged on the working system. If I close it's cover and plug cord in - it begin charging properly even after I open laptop back and begin to work.

Otherwise, if I open the battery settings, it just states "Not charging" in battery status.

I searched the solution, but all of them mostly outdated and supposes this behavior helps to save battery life and that it starts charging back after certain threshold. Still, now I'm trying to charge it from 40% and it's still "Not charging" (nor running down though).

Also, I've updated my system to the recent 22.04 LTS - didn't help.

My laptop is Lenovo ThinkPad T15.

How to make system charge the battery back to 100% regardless the moment when I plug the power cord in?